# Constructive analysis and synthetic differential geometry

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, constructive-mathematics, synthetic-differential

I am curious if (any of) the various inequivalent constructions of the real line in constructive mathematics can be used to build a model of Kock and Lawvere's synthetic differential geometry? In other words, do any of the constructions of the real line (in say HoTT) satisfy the Kock-Lawvere axiom for a class of functions which deserve to be called smooth? If not, how can we "augment" the real line with nilpotent infinitesimals for this to be true?

I am a complete novice when it comes to constructive mathematics, but I'm reasonably comfortable with Anders Kock's synthetic differential geometry texts. Unfortunately, I haven't had a chance to read the Models of SDG text yet, so I apologize if this is covered there.

Comment: Do you mean, can one build a sheaf model of SDG inside constructive mathematics by starting from these real numbers, analogously to how one builds a sheaf model of SDG inside classical mathematics by starting from the classical real numbers?  Or do you mean, can one prove inside a particular model of constructive mathematics that these real numbers satisfy the Kock-Lawvere axioms for a line object?

Comment: Sorry for being imprecise; I'm curious about both of these, actually. Say in HoTT if we build a real line from the rationals using one of the various constructions, can we show that the Kock-Lawvere axiom holds for those functions on the line which we would like to consider smooth?

Comment: Not in any straightforward way, since “x^2 = 0 implies x = 0” holds constructively, but not in SDG.

Comment: @Matt F. Hm that's disappointing. Does this hold for all the usual constructions of the real line in constructive mathematics?

Comment: Yes.  After all, the proof is easy:  For each n, |x|>0 or |x|<1/n, but the first option is incompatible with x^2=0.  So for each n, |x|<1/n.  So x=0.  For anything worth calling "a construction of the real line in constructive mathematics", that argument should work.

Comment: In SDG, the ring holding the infinitesimals does not a priori have to do anything with real numbers. For example, in the big Zariski model of SDG it is the affine line. In the most general version of the axioms, as given in "[Toposes of laws of motion](http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~wlawvere/ToposMotion.pdf)" this ring is given by the basepoint preserving endomorphisms of a tiny object; its intended meaning is indeed, as Lawvere says, the ring of real quantities viewed as time speed-ups or retardations. However I see no way to relate it to "actual" real numbers in general.

Comment: @MattF. Why would one expect that any construction of the real line in constructive mathematics has the property that "|x|<1/n for each n implies x=0"? I know this is part of the mainstream view on real numbers, but why is it also something a constructivist expects? (Like the OP I'm also a novice constructivist, so apologies if my question seems strange.)

Comment: @MichaelBächtold, for interesting math over the reals, you need some criterion for equality.  Here are a few possibilities:  a) Cauchy, (forall n, |x| < 1/n) -> x = 0; b) Dedekind, (forall q, x < q iff 0 < q) -> x = 0; c) Kock-Lawvere, (forall y, y^2 = 0 -> xy = 0) -> x = 0.  Both a and b have the consequence that you asked about, and they work with or are equivalent to the constructive idea of approximation.  If you have a criterion of equality like c, without this consequence, I’d probably reject the word “constructive” to describe it.  So this is close to a definitional question.

Comment: @MattF. I'm not sure I understand you correctly. It seems your reason to reject c) is more a matter of expectations (which properties the reals should have) and not so much related to constructivism? On the other hand, if I'm not mistaken, a constructivists would reject the standard axiomatic approach to SDG (in particular the KL axiom) since it postulates that a certain map is an isomorphism, without constructing an inverse. (Could one complain that "KL does not compute", just how initially constructivists would complain "Univalence does not compute"?)

Comment: @MichaelBächtold, I don’t make any comments about constructivists, since almost everyone now interested in constructive math is post-constructivist.  But there is a body of theorems and meta-theorems and intuitions and aesthetics for constructive analysis, which I find coherent and sometimes useful and beautiful and enjoyable.  I mentioned the KL axiom because I find it beautiful in its own way, but I choose to put it in a separate category from constructive analysis.

Comment: @MattF What is a "post-constructivist"? Google wasn't helpful with this term.

Comment: @MattF. I would not call your (c) a "criterion of equality", not like (a) and (b): its conclusion is indeed an equality, but its hypothesis also involves equalities, so it's rather a *property* that the entire ring satisfies.  I think Michael is asking a good question, which I would phrase precisely like this: is there any constructive construction of a ring which (1) produces the Kock-Lawvere line object when interpreted in a standard model of SDG, and (2) produces the classical real numbers when interpreted in classical mathematics?  I suspect not, but I don't think I have a proof.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the smooth-topos models of SDG, the situation is generally something like this.  The internally-definable Cauchy real numbers $\mathbf{R}_c$ are the sheaf of locally constant $\mathbb{R}$-valued functions, while the internally-definable Dedekind real numbers $\mathbf{R}_d$ are the sheaf of continuous $\mathbb{R}$-valued functions.  In between these there is the sheaf $\mathbf{R}_s$ of *smooth* $\mathbb{R}$-valued functions, $\mathbf{R}_c \to \mathbf{R}_s \to \mathbf{R}_d$, which in turn is a quotient of the "line object" $\mathbf{R}_l$ that contains infinitesimals.  Despite much trying, I don't know of any internal construction that produces $\mathbf{R}_s$ or $\mathbf{R}_l$ in these toposes; it seems that they have to be considered extra structure with which the topos is equipped.  However, they are related to other structure it has, such as [differential cohesion](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/differential+cohesive+%28infinity%2C1%29-topos).  You may also be interested in [smooth structures on a topos](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/smooth+structure+on+a+topos).

Comment: If I understand Lawvere's intent correctly, when objects of your topos are certain functors on $\mathbb R$-algebras, then the forgetful functor should correspond to $\mathbb R_l$, with the tiny object $D$ represented by $\mathbb R[\varepsilon]/(\varepsilon^2=0)$ sitting inside. What I cannot figure out right away is what is the subobject $R$ of $D^D$ consisting of zero preserving endomorphisms that Lawvere would consider. Is this $R$ isomorphic to any of the $\mathbb R_c$, $\mathbb R_l$, $\mathbb R_s$ or $\mathbb R_d$??

Comment: Yes, that's $\mathbf{R}_l$.  I don't know the answer to the other question, but you could check Moerdijk-Reyes to see if they consider it, or write out the definition and unravel it as a sheaf.

Comment: If I am not mistaken I get $\mathbb R_l$. Thus given $D$ without $\mathbb R_l$ one can indeed recover $\mathbb R_l$ from it. I don't however know whether imposing on $D$ some abstract conditions on top of tininess one can determine it up to isomorphism in this particular topos.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Imposing some abstract conditions on $D$ to recover $R$ seems to be one of the suggestions of Lawvere. See for example his article [Euler’s Continuum Functorially Vindicated](https://github.com/mattearnshaw/lawvere/blob/master/pdfs/2011-euler's-continuum-functorially-vindicated.pdf) or [this talk](https://youtu.be/pKWYa9sc5UI?t=3233) by Peter Johnstone.

Comment: @MichaelBächtold Yes thanks, this is what I should mention, I did not know these sources. However if I am not overlooking something, the following question is still open: fix the "smooth topos" where you want to work. Is it possible to impose on an abstract object $T$ there some abstract conditions which would imply that it is isomorphic to $D$ (square zero part of $\mathbb R_l$ which you are forbidden to refer to directly).

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე the n-lab and other sources call $D$ the _smallest_ (non-trivial) tiny object. Might a property like "$D$ has no sub objects besides the point and itself" help to characterise it?

Comment: @MikeShulman If we are working in a constructive foundation like say HoTT from the beginning to construct our real line and so on, can we still build the Dubuc topos or other "well-adapted" model of SDG?

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ you can certainly build something like them.  The abstract theory of sheaf toposes on sites works fine constructively, and there are constructive notions of smooth function and so on.  I don't know how many of the same properties the resulting toposes have though.